# Cross-platform C++ tool chain

Tags: c++, .net, macos, cross-platform, build-process

I'm a die-hard .NET developer with limited experience in C++.  I'm really familiar with how happily interpreted languages (and scripting languages) work cross-platform, but what about C++?

I realize that GCC/GPP and some other compilers sorta work multi-platform with the right compiler flags, and I understand that the STL is normalized between compilers, but what else am I missing?  I'll need to do audio in/out, high accuracy timers, and I'll need to do multithreading.  I don't think any of these things are supported in the STL, so I'll be needing a cross-platform library of some type, right?  Which one should I use?

I'm aiming to support the latest Mac and Windows platforms.  This is a shared framework/sdk and won't have a UI.  I plan on writing the UI in a native language such as Objective-C/Cocoa and .NET/WPF (both which have excellent native UI support).

So what should my tool chain look like?  Should I be using GCC/GPP or MinGW?  What other 'libraries' should I integrate that will function cross platform?  I'd like to setup my build environment to 'just work' such that I can build a Mac compatible binary and a windows compatible binary (32 bit and 64 bit).  How can I do that?

At this point, I'll be writing code for each platform so that I can interop with this my C++ multiplatform framework sdk/api thingy.  In windows, I think this will look like a managed DLL, is that right?  Any thoughts on how I'll do this on a Mac?

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Thanks for the suggestions,
Brett

Comment: Threading in the STL is supported if you use a recent enough compiler (it's new in C++11). GCC 4.6 and MSVC support it, I bet clang as well.

Comment: @J.N. Yes, clang/libc++ supports `std::thread`.

Comment: Since when are .Net languages native? (besides C++/CLI) Before attempting something like this, clearing up the definition of "native" and how it relates to C++ and cross-platform (and how a compiler does not cross-platform make) might be useful.

Comment: @peachykeen, I see what you're getting at about 'native' here.  I was actually referring to the 'primary' language recommended for an average developer on a given platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Your real goal here should be to write portable C++ -- you get portability by keeping your language use clean, not by using a particular compiler.

2) Some of what you want, like audio i/o, is fairly inherently platform dependent. You can, however, cleanly isolate the platform dependencies inside particular modules and conditionally compile a set of platform support files on each platform.

3) Stuff like multithreading can be done in a platform independent manner using standard libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Getting into subjective territory but for a developer used to working with large, do-it-all kind of frameworks like those we find in .NET, QT would probably be your best cross-platform C++ analogy (though I am not a huge fan of it). There you have your threads, XML I/O, localization, sockets, high accuracy timers, GUI building blocks, etc.

> [...] and I'll need to do multithreading. I don't think any of these things
>   are supported in the STL [...]

Just a small thing, but the STL is limited to describing the aggregate containers and generic algorithms of the C++ Standard Library. It is not synonymous, but C++11 has specifications in the standard library for concurrency support. However, popular compilers are still slow to support it fully. You also have boost if you need threads for the time being: http://www.boost.org which is an extremely cross-platform library.

As for building an API that can happily plug in to various environments (.NET, Cocoa, etc), your best, most cross-platform option is actually to expose a C API (you're free to implement it using C++). It'll cause the least headaches this way (no issues with name mangling, trying to interop with complex, user-defined C++ types, etc.).

I recommend you get some practice with building DLLs/shared libraries in C++ as a way to extend .NET and Cocoa applications (ex: C++ module used in objective-C) before you start trying to develop a grand library.

Answer (score 0):

For timing the standard library has `<chrono>`, which has nanosecond resolution on Mac. Unfortunately it's only got millisecond resolution on Windows as of the VS11 Beta. I'm hoping they fix it without too much delay.